# How is the featured site chosen?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, featured-site

I saw the featured site on [Stack Exchange home page](https://stackexchange.com/).

[image]

How is the featured site being decided? Is there any formula or is it just an editor's pick? Can a site be repeated even before any site is featured?

Comment: Most likely a manual process, done by a Community Manager.

Comment: Most likely a random process, done by a cold, unfeeling robot.

Comment: Most likely I should not make assumptions like this. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a random selection from the list of graduated sites.

So, conceivably, the same site could feature a couple of days in a row.

Comment: Totally random, no weight whatsoever? Quite frustrating IMO! :-)