# Does the featured site get measurably more traffic?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, statistics, traffic, featured-site

Is there any significant increase in traffic to the featured-site of any particular day?  How large is this effect?

For people unfamiliar with the featured site: it's a graduated site [randomly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235035/172266) chosen and listed in the sidebar of [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com).  Today it's [quantitative finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/).  I don't think I've ever been to the site.  Does it get any significantly more traffic today, or on other days that the site was featured, than it did yesterday or tomorrow?

I suspect the effect is very small, if at all measurable, in particular since the lowest traffic sites, which aren't graduated, are ineligible.

(NB: featured site has nothing to do with featured questions or bounties.)

Comment: Bounties are overrated, and ever were.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Featured site has nothing to do with featured questions or bounties.

Comment: Given that in more than 4 years this is the first time I hear of featured sites, my guess would be "no" ;-)

Comment: Probably the next question would be: how many users know/use/are interested in existing features of [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com/)? There are: Hot Network Questions (I know some use this), Real-time Questions (some bots use this, but humans?), Today's Featured Site, Top Network Askers, Top Network Sites.

Comment: I've been using Stack Exchange for nearly 6 years, and I'm a mod on quite a few sites, and this is the first time I have heard of featured sites...

Comment: I guess we could determine which site was featured on a certain day from the Wayback Machine copies of stackexchange.com, and compare those to the site analytics; unfortunately, that would require a lot of volunteers with 25k/5k on the respective sites.

Comment: But my gut feeling says the # of HNQ questions on a certain day matters way more than this single link. Probably even Stack Exchange itself doesn't know this; there's no 'referral' slug in the link in that widget.

Comment: While admittedly I am but a grasshopper compared to many of these venerable users, the only reason I ever go to the homepage is when I'm transiting to the list of all sites - I don't think I've ever stopped to look around the page, since I'm there with a very specific purpose (to go somewhere else).