# Allow sites in Beta to be chosen for the Today's Featured Site

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, beta-sites, featured-site

As described in [How is the featured site chosen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235026/how-is-the-featured-site-chosen)

> - How is the featured site chosen?
>
> - It is a random selection from the *list of graduated sites*.

Could we allow Beta sites to rotate as well with the idea of allowing them to potentially get more attention and traffic? (assuming there is any [measurable positive impact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317093/does-the-featured-site-get-measurably-more-traffic?noredirect=1&lq=1) of a site showing up there)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, we should do this. I am even proposing a step further: replace the HNQ list in the sidebar with the featured site.

[One of the key goals of the HNQ is site promotion.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha/319382)

Replacing it would have two advantages:

1. New users would learn about the Stack Exchange network.
2. There would be no confusion due to “strange” titles that are displayed out of context.

One disadvantage would be that great questions of a site would no longer be shown. A solution could be that the sidebar widget shows the three most upvoted questions from the last month. (Or any other selection algorithm)

Comment: One could als decide what to show (HNQ/site) based on loginstate/rep, etc.