# Should Stack Overflow be featured?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stackexchange.com, featured-site

Browsing the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), I noticed that "Today's Featured Site" is Stack Overflow:

[image: Today's Featured Site screenshot showing Stack Overflow]

[Given that Stack Overflow's traffic is greater than that of all other SE sites combined](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic), is it really necessary to feature this one? Taking SO out of the rotation could help drive more traffic to the other sites in the network.

It would also be nice to [allow sites in beta to be chosen for "Today's Featured Site"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320405/346823).

Comment: if memory serves, several years ago someone from SE team mentioned that total traffic of all other sites combined became slightly greater than that of Stack Overflow. There is also a chance that taking it totally off from hot questions (as opposed to current very heavy penalising), may have an effect opposite to desired one, as [discussed eg here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397231/839601)

Comment: Yes, it should be featured to promote teams